# How to replace line in the file if exists PHP

Tags: php, web-development-server

So, I have a code that based on user's input write data to the file. Basically user select the date and the workout which on submit get written to the file. When I try to set it up to check if the string (date) already exist in the file I cannot make it work so that existing line is replaced.

**Current code that is writing user's input to the file:**

```
<?php
   include 'index.php';
   $pickdate = $_POST['date'];
   $workout = $_POST['workout'];
   $date = '   \''.$pickdate .'\' : \'<a href="../routines/'.$workout.'" target="_blank"><span>'.basename($workout,'.txt').'</span></a>\',' .PHP_EOL;
   $file = 'test.js';

   // Open the file to get existing content
   $current = file_get_contents($file);

   // Append a new workout to the file
   $current .= $date;
   $current = preg_replace('/};/', "", $current);
   $current = $current.'};';

   // Write the contents back to the file
   file_put_contents($file, $current);
   header("location:index.php");
?>
```

My attempts were with if statement but again I couldn't manage to write the code that will replace the line with if exists. This is what I have:

```
<?php
   include 'index.php';
   $pickdate = $_POST['date'];
   $workout = $_POST['workout'];
   $date = '   \''.$pickdate .'\' : \'<a href="../routines/'.$workout.'" target="_blank"><span>'.basename($workout,'.txt').'</span></a>\',' .PHP_EOL;
   $file = 'test.js';

   // Open the file to get existing content
   $current = file_get_contents($file);

   if (strpos($current, '   \''.$pickdate .'\'') ) {
     #here is where I struggle#
   }
   else {
    // Append a new workout to the file
   $current .= $date;
   $current = preg_replace('/};/', "", $current);
   $current = $current.'};';

   // Write the contents back to the file
   file_put_contents($file, $current);
   }
  header("location:index.php");
?>
```

***Currently it is doing this***

```
08-04-2014 : Chest
08-05-2014 : Legs
08-04-2014 : Back
```

***I want this***

Now when user choose August 4th again that line to be replaced with new/same choice of workout depending what user selects.

```
08-04-2014 : Back
08-05-2014 : Legs
```

Can someone help with the part where I struggle to make this work. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: *"Can someone help with the part where I `struggle` to make this work."* - Why struggle with a text file? Use a DB and make your life easier.

Comment: Why are you looking for `};` in your `preg_replace`? There's nothing like that in the file you showed.

Comment: Read the file line by line, and explode the line on `" : "`. Then compare the date part to the data the user gave. If it's the same, change the workout with the new workout. After going through the whole file, write the lines back to the file.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Eventually I will get there as I get enough knowledge. User's input is written to the .js file as the results are being displayed on the dynamic calendar.@Barmar So very last line of the .js file has to be `};` and by that line of code I am removing `};` from previous lines so I do not have. Is there a way you can give me an example how to do it?

Comment: I understand. *Sidenote:* Make sure you protect your `.txt` file(s) from prying eyes using `.htacess` and setting proper permissions. When you do get started in DB, remember to use prepared statements.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I will definitely do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Barmar in the comments:

```
$current = trim(file_get_contents($file));
$current_lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $current);

/* saved already */
$saved = false;

foreach($current_lines as $line_num => $line) {
    /* either regex or explode, we explode easier on the brain xD */
    list($date_line, $workout_line) = explode(' : ', $line);
    echo "$date_line -> $workout_line \n";

    if($date == $date_line) {
        /* rewrite */
        $current_lines[$line_num] = "$date : $workout";
        $saved = true;
        /* end loop */
        break;
    }        
}

/* append to the end */
if(!$saved) {
    $current_lines[] = "$date : $workout";
}

file_put_contents($file, implode(PHP_EOL, $current_lines));
```

So, you explode the file, go thru it, line by line, if found overwrite that line, if not append it to the end of the array, then glue it back together and put it back in the file.

You'll get the idea.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I couldn't make it to work. Maybe I am implementing it wrong. As I understand I put this code instead of mine with if statement, is that right? or if I am wrong can you please explain me better as I am not that PHP savy? Thank you